# Apache solr access protected parameters

Tags: search

I wanted to access the keyword being searched in the Apache Solr. Thus i used the [hook_apachesolr_process_results](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21apachesolr%21apachesolr.api.php/function/hook_apachesolr_process_results/7) Hook to access the $query variable.
But I am unable to access the keyword as it is inside a SolrBaseQuery **[params:protected]** object.
It throws a error saying **Fatal error:  Cannot access protected property SolrBaseQuery::$params**
Is there any way of accessing the protected parameters of Apache Solr or is there any other approach to get the keyword being searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a good idea to read through the code for a class you're trying to work with.

For example, a quick look through [the code](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!apachesolr!Solr_Base_Query.php/class/SolrBaseQuery/7) yields [`SolrBaseQuery::getParams()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21apachesolr%21Solr_Base_Query.php/function/SolrBaseQuery%3A%3AgetParams/7), whose responsibility is to ensure accuracy for, and return, the protected `$params` array.